# Connecting to a plc with server using Pymcprotocol

Tags: python, networking, server, lan, plc

I am Swapnil and I have no experience with servers. I am trying to connect to a Mitsubishi fx5u PlC from a server but I get a timeout error when I try. But when we try to connect it to connect it with any other laptop or PC, it get connected without any problem.
On the other hand when I have tried to ping the PLC from the server it it returns the ping that means I have a link to the PLC.

I am using Hewlett Packard with windows server on it has , I have tried :

1. Tried to configure the IP of the server
2. Tried to make the gateway same
3. Tried disabling windows defender.

Code:

```
import pymcprotocol
plc1 = pymcprotocol.Type3E()
plc1.connect("192.168.250.6", 1200)
```

error  :
`TimeoutError : timed out`

My Server IP is 192.168.250.90.[Code with error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tF3R2.jpg)

1. I have tried to reconfigure the ip of the serve IP.
2. Tried disabling the windows defender.
3. Tried to reconfigure PLC.

Please help me to troubleshoot this issue.

Thank you in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

This is likely not a pymcprotocol error; it's more probable that there's a network issue. I recommend trying the following steps for further investigation:

1. Verify the network connection between your server and the PLC's port.

   Use the "ping" command to send ICMP packets and check for responses. A successful response means that ICMP is functioning correctly, but you should also ensure that your server can connect to the PLC's port. Since your screenshots indicate a Windows system, you can use the `telnet host port` command. If you need guidance on enabling telnet on Windows 10, you can refer to [this link](https://www.lifewire.com/what-is-telnet-2626026).
2. Check the PLC's IP whitelist settings.

   Some PLCs have access control features, such as IP whitelists. You can find these settings in the PLC configuration panel.
3. Utilize Wireshark to capture all traffic between the server and the PLC.

Answer (score 0):

> A and FX series are not supportted because they does not support 3E or 4E type.
> https://pypi.org/project/pymcprotocol/

In my case, i use Q series, just make sure Port 1200 (in your case) is a "MC Protocol" with "TCP". And always hard reboot your PLC after change the Parameter.

[again, hard reboot after write parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uf3x2.jpg)